# SSRS 2008 row color expression changes 0 value cell

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have an expression that changes the background color of a row based on an active status of "Active". Everything works well except that other cells with a value of 0 get set to my inactive color. So if I am setting my conditional based on the word "Active" then why are the cells on active rows with a 0 value getting set as well?

[image: Grid example]

Comment: I added a picture of the issue. Even though the row is active, that one cell with the 0 is highlighted. I am making a comparison on the text "Active" so I can't understand why a 0 is causing this.

Comment: Can you post the expression for the Hidden property of that cell?

Comment: =IIF(Fields!Status.Value = "Active",Nothing,"#FFE4ED")

Comment: Does the 0 have the same affect in all columns?  Check the same expression at the column level and the tablix level and see if there is anything that might be setting the bgcolor based on a value of 0.

Comment: It seems to be affecting my matrix column grouping cells. I group on a date value and do a countrows() for the total. If it is 0 then the inactive color is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure why this was happening but, I fixed it by adding a conditional on my grouping column. It looked for a 0 value and set my background to Nothing. This was done at the row level already but had no affect. I had to set  the column also for it to work.